Inquiry on maximum location data collection frequency on Android and IOS
I'm working on a project that involves collecting location data from an application running in the background on both Android and iOS devices. I need precise information, source regarding the maximum number of location data points that can be collected per hour or per day by an application operating in the background on both platforms.
Despite extensive research, I have not been able to find detailed and comprehensive data on these aspects. If anyone could provide documentation, user guides, case studies, or insights from their experience, it would be greatly appreciated.
